# How to solve this linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am dealing with the following example:

$$
\pmatrix{
    -1 & -2& -3 \\
     3 & 2 & 1 \\
1& 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 4& 1 
    }* 
\pmatrix{
   x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
    }= \pmatrix{
   -6\\
6 \\
3 \\
7 \\ 
 }$$

I know I should solve that matrix with gauß' elimination, but my problem is that there are only $x_1 $ to $x_3 $, so I do not know how to interprete this example?

Comment: Solve it like you normally would, and the last equation should change to $0x_1+0x_2+0x_3=0$, otherwise the system is inconsistent.

Comment: Check this Wiki link for a little more information on inconsistent or over-determined systems : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system

Comment: @Clayton so you would kill the last row and then have 3 equations?

Comment: @maximus: It happens naturally (unless the system is inconsistent). This is because the basis only consists of three elements, so the fourth one has to be a linear combination of the first $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Clayton noted do the G.E., as you always do for any matrix. Here you have $$A:=\left( \begin{array}
    ~-1 & -2& -3&~~ -6 \\
     3 & 2 & 1&~~~~~~~   6 \\
1& 1 & 1&~~~~~~~   3 \\
    2 & 4& 1&~~~~~~~   7 \\ 
    \end{array} \right)$$ which by doing some process became:  $$\sim\left( \begin{array}
        11 & 1& 1&~~~~~~~ 3 \\
     0 & 1 & 2&~~~~~~~   3 \\
0& 0 & -5&~~~  -5 \\
    0 & 0& 0&~~~~~~~   0 \\ 
    \end{array} \right)$$ This means that the forth equation in the original system was dependent to other 3 equations. It is clear now that your solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is unique and can be found easily.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes of course. I assumed the OP already knows that in G.E. we do the same rules on the constant matrix as well as we are doing on the coefficient matrix. Honestly, I wanted to add more for the OP that the system shows 4 plane in $R^3$ which has no a vivid single intersection as well. I should say that Clayton started to tell the OP the main point. I wrote some of the way he wanted to say here. Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe something to do with \begin{array} usually has formatting like \begin{array}{cccc} ...?

Comment: @adamW: You are right. I fixed it. there was a gap and if you wanted to see that, you would do that. I add a ~ for doing it right. ;-)

Comment: I don't want to stray off topic too much so I will delete these soon but - I've always wanted to do a dashed line instead of solid as with \begin{array}{ccc|c}, I end up using \phantom{-}1 or something for alignment. Never knew of using ~ is that supposed to be like a single space?

Comment: @adamW:Thanks. It is very kind of you but, you know, I am interested to know how can I write $<A\mid b>$ when we know the matrix $A$ and $b$ in a system with a segment between them in Latex. You see through my answer that I made a big gap there to build this.

Comment: this works: your line is \begin{array} change it to (add at the end) \begin{array}{ccc|c} which stands for center center center a line (as you describe) then center

Comment: I keep your advice for next. Thanks.

Comment: Helpful, once again! +1